# "Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs" when deploying OSGi module for Liferay on Tomcat

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, liferay, osgi

I'm currently developing a REST API with JAX-RS and Jackson in a Maven project but I'm facing some issues when I try to deploy it to the server.

```
2019-06-14 11:35:18.832 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 9d0f0e6b-9ad0-4d64-b221-2bde32f797ee][BundleStartStopLogger:39] STARTED XXXXREST_1.0.0 [1004]
2019-06-14 11:35:19.801 ERROR [fileinstall-C:/liferay-ce-portal-7.1.2-ga3/osgi/modules][org_apache_felix_fileinstall:97] Error while starting bundle: file:/C:/liferay-ce-portal-7.1.2-ga3/osgi/modules/XXXXREST.jar 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.xxxx.xxxx [995]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs; version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"_ [Sanitized]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1258)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1230)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1218)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:507)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)
2019-06-14 11:35:19.816 ERROR [fileinstall-C:/liferay-ce-portal-7.1.2-ga3/osgi/modules][org_apache_felix_fileinstall:97] Error while starting bundle: file:/C:/liferay-ce-portal-7.1.2-ga3/osgi/modules/XXXXREST.jar 
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.xxxxx.xxxxx [995]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.ws.rs; version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"_ [Sanitized]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:428)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1258)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1230)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)
2019-06-14 11:35:33.958 INFO  [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 9d0f0e6b-9ad0-4d64-b221-2bde32f797ee][PortletHotDeployListener:288] 1 portlet for XXXXREST is available for use
2019-06-14 11:35:35.599 ERROR [Refresh Thread: Equinox Container: 9d0f0e6b-9ad0-4d64-b221-2bde32f797ee][com_liferay_portal_osgi_web_wab_extender:97] Catastrophic initialization failure! Shutting down XXXXREST WAB due to: The URI scheme bundleentry of the URI bundleentry://995.fwk1108589630/com/xxxxx/xxxxxx/domain/CommunityResource.class is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs._Try using a different deployment mechanism such as explicitly declaring root resource and provider classes using an extension of javax.ws.rs.core.Application  [Sanitized]
com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.ScannerException: The URI scheme bundleentry of the URI bundleentry://995.fwk1108589630/com/xxxxx/xxxxx/domain/CommunityResource.class is not supported. Package scanning deployment is not supported for such URIs._Try using a different deployment mechanism such as explicitly declaring root resource and provider classes using an extension of javax.ws.rs.core.Application [Sanitized]
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:228)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:142)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.<init>(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.AsyncAttributeAdapterServlet.init(AsyncAttributeAdapterServlet.java:54)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.adapter.ServletExceptionAdapter.init(ServletExceptionAdapter.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.registration.EndpointRegistration.init(EndpointRegistration.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.ContextController.doAddServletRegistration(ContextController.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.context.ContextController.addServletRegistration(ContextController.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.customizer.ContextServletTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ContextServletTrackerCustomizer.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.customizer.ContextServletTrackerCustomizer.addingService(ContextServletTrackerCustomizer.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:943)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.FilteredServiceListener.serviceChanged(FilteredServiceListener.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEventPrivileged(ServiceRegistry.java:891)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.publishServiceEvent(ServiceRegistry.java:804)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistrationImpl.register(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.serviceregistry.ServiceRegistry.registerService(ServiceRegistry.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:469)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:1004)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.initServlets(WabBundleProcessor.java:692)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabBundleProcessor.init(WabBundleProcessor.java:225)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer._initWabBundle(WebBundleDeployer.java:186)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WebBundleDeployer.doStart(WebBundleDeployer.java:85)
    at com.liferay.portal.osgi.web.wab.extender.internal.WabFactory$WABExtension.start(WabFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.createExtension(AbstractExtender.java:259)
    at org.apache.felix.utils.extender.AbstractExtender.modifiedBundle(AbstractExtender.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:488)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleTracker.java:1)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:232)
    at org.osgi.util.tracker.BundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleTracker.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:137)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.start(ModuleContainer.java:777)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.applyDelta(ModuleContainer.java:768)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.resolveAndApply(ModuleContainer.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.resolve(ModuleContainer.java:484)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer.refresh(ModuleContainer.java:1028)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerWiring.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1409)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerWiring.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Apparently it has something to do with javax.ws.rs package. Maybe Liferay or Tomcat are using their own dependency which collides with the version that I'm using?

So far I've tried adding this line to my bnd.bnd file:

```
Import-Package: javax.ws.rs; version="[1.1.0,2.0.0)"
```

I also tried adding the dependency on my pom.xml (I tried multiple versions: 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.1, 2.1.1):

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
     <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I also tried adding to project's build path those *javax.ws.rs-api-2.X.X.jar*

Any ideas on what could be causing this? I don't know what else should I try.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't tested this on 7.1 but javax.ws.rs is a provided dependency you just needs to put the right version in the maven file with the provided scope. The manifest should then he correctly generated. You should not force version to the import especially not the way how you did as your intervention will break the import generation. What does the manifest file in the jar say?

Comment: This is what I get: https://pastebin.com/HkjveWs9

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to Miroslav's comment, I didn't find javax.ws.rs-api in the provided dependencies. Thus, you're satisfying the build-time dependency (for the compiler) with your dependency declaration.

The generated artifact (your own bundle) still has a runtime dependency on javax.ws.rs-api-*.jar, and you'll need to deploy it as well: Just drop it into your `${liferay.home}/deploy` folder. Now it's available for any upcoming bundle that has a dependency on it.

I'm suspecting that Miroslav did this some time ago, and now has it available in his runtime. Or I've tested on a wrong version (I've used DXP 7.2) or missed something.

Comment: Well, I no longer have that unresolved requirement, but now I got new ones: https://pastebin.com/9dk6Q8KB I tried adding the unresolved jars (adal4j-0.0.2.jar and mssql-jdbc-7.2.2.jre8.jar) but nothing happens.